# Why are the masses hanging from a pulley not considered in its moment of inertia?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, torque, inertia

My physics textbook showed a diagram of a pulley with mass with 2 blocks hanging from either side by a massless string. They calculated the moment of inertia by  finding an approximation of the pulley as a cylinder, but I am confused on why they did not include the 2 blocks hanging as part of the moment of inertia, as they have mass. If anyone could explain this to me, thank you!

Comment: The moment of inertia is not applicable to objects that are in pure translation.

Answer (score 1):

The masses were not part of the body that had to rotate, so they did not contribute to the Moment of Inertia.  The masses were simply the forces acting to cause the pulley to rotate.